# Should watch be used for synchronous function in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I want to call a method which is not async whenever the state changes.
From what I understand, computed properties are used to return a value by doing some operations on state, and not to call a method. And watchers are used for async calling async functions generally.
I am new to Vue and think I am missing something basic here. 
How can I call a method upon changing state? Can it be done using watchers? Would it be good practice?

Comment: You should use `computed` when you want to have an additional state variable which is derived synchroniously from your other state variables. For everything else, I would use a regular watcher. Many cases are however already covered by just using `computed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vuejs guide says:

> While computed properties are more appropriate in most cases, there are times when a custom watcher is necessary. That’s why Vue provides a more generic way to react to data changes through the watch option. This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or **expensive operations in response to changing data**.

So you can call a method inside a watcher, even if it doesn't contain asynchronous operations. There's nothing wrong.